# Configuring GeoTools to convert graphic objects to shapefiles without using filesystem?

Tags: geotools, memory

By default, GeoTools (20.2) tries to convert the graphic objects into shapefiles on the disk. We want to skip this step and have GeoTools keep the file contents in memory (and return it as a byte array or other memory object) so we can stream it elsewhere. We have security requirements that prevent us from accessing the filesystem so all operations must be done in memory. This lack of functionality could preclude us from using GeoTools if it cannot accomplish this.

It seems easy enough to do this using Java streams. using streams to write the data into any kind of memory or file buffer. I need to understand if this was (or why it was not) done as it appears to be a simple "design for but not with" convention at its simplest.

Is there a need to remain backward compatible with older versions of Java that don't support some of these functions and what is the hard limit on Java versions like Java 6?

Comment: By definition, a shapefile is a filesystem-based entity. You need to use a streamable format.

Comment: the limit is java8 - and the reason it isn't done is because shapefiles are only designed to be stored on disk. If you need in memory then use a `FeatureCollection` which is designed for that

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: For reasons that I cannot divulge, the design directed us to use ShapeFiles as a medium. A side-effect of this decision is that we cannot FTP/scp the files to the host system so we package the bytes into a packet and send it over the network. The issue then is, "why do we have to write the files to the disk?" If we have the contents in memory, then we can use them as-is OR dump it to an actual file. Seems the only option is dump it to a file? I was curious if there were settings or some other method to access the byte buffer before it was written to the filesystem and skip the filesystem step?

Comment: You'll either need to write to disk or add functionality to the project. But best bet is not to use a shapefile, compressed geojson or gml would work much better in this situation

Comment: @IanTurton mind putting that into an actual answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll either need to write to disk or add functionality to the project. But best bet is not to use a shapefile, compressed geojson or gml would work much better in this situation

Comment: So I would need to, at a minimum, extend an existing class to add or change the functionality locally in my source, or to augment the codebase for the OpenDDS project to add the functionality that I'm looking for so others can use it if they choose. Thank you.